# Update : How display data got with a request sent from a mother page in a popup?

Tags: javascript, html

Context :
I want to display data in a popup window.

On a html mother page, I have the under html with a select. In the select there are two onchange functions : we don't need the first. The second gets data from a database (based on which option I chose in the select) and should display the data with the function OpenAndSet (which is wrote under too).

```js
function GetTheCLubOf (clubname) {
    return [{'Club': {'firstname': clubname, 'adresse': '', 'latitude': '', 'longitude': ''}}];
}

function OpenAndSet (xhr) {
    window.open('/testpopup/Forms/clubForm.html', 'Modifier le club', 'width=500px');

    let values = Split(Object.values(Parse(xhr.responseText)));
    console.log(values);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);

    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = GetValue(values, 1, 'firstname');
    document.getElementById('adress').innerHTML = GetValue(values, 1, 'adresse');
    document.getElementById('lati').innerHTML = GetValue(values, 1, 'latitude');
    document.getElementById('longi').innerHTML = GetValue(values, 1, 'longitude');
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> Test </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css">
</head>
<body>
  <select id="clubsList" onchange="NoDAL('Select',GetCategoriesOf(SelectedOptionOf('clubsList')), password.value, SetCategories) ; NoDAL('Select', GetTheCLubOf(SelectedOptionOf('clubsList')), password.value, OpenAndSet)">
    <option selected="selected"> Sélectionner un club </option>
  </select>
</body>
```

And I want the OpenAndSet function to display data in a popup "clubForm.html" :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> My clubForm </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clubForm.css">
</head>
<body>
    <aside id="clubaside">
        <h2> Info du club  </h2>
        <p id="name"> nom du club </p>
        <p id="adress"> adresse </p>
        <p id="lati"> latitude </p>
        <p id="longi"> longitude </p>
        <div class="boutons">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
            </svg>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't know how to do this. Maybe use localStorage ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. The easiest way to do this with JavaScript and HTML is with a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in a page).

Comment: Why button have `onclick="ShowInfos()"` where in your js there is no such function? Why are you passing `win` variable to `GetItemsFromStorage` and the use it with `win.document.get....` when you can write simply `document.get....`? Where and when are you invoking `SetItemsInStorage` function? You snippet should answer those questions. Without them we are not able to debug it.

Comment: I tried to reformulate my problem with code we need.

Answer (score -1):

> Document.getElementById

Returns the object of the element

> HTMLElement.prototype.innerHTML

Returns the HTML inside the element

> HTMLElement.prototype.outerHTML

Returns the HTML element along with the innerHTML

You're also getting an item from the `localStorage` (somehow named "the firstname is:") which isn't a valid item.

*See more about HTMLElement.prototype.innerHTML at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML*